# Gradle sync failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Version : 3.2.1 for Windows 64-bit

I updated to the most recent version of Android Studio, and once again it has caught fire.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue below ?

```
Gradle sync failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslUtil.findInjections(GroovyDslUtil.java:823)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.getInjections(GroovyDslParser.java:280)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.lambda$fetchDependencies$1(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:664)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:913)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.fetchDependencies(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:663)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.setupDependencies(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:673)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.resolve(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:654)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Please let me know if you found any solution

Comment: @kj007 I really hope you mean 'studio'. It is 3.2.1

Comment: Yeah sorry for typo

Comment: Did you clean the project?? Or can you please downgrade to 3.1.4 if it works might be some issue with latest version as it’s just released

Comment: @kj007 Yes I cleaned the project. If I can't find a fix I will try downgrading .

Comment: Would you mind posting your build.gradle files? That may help us to determine what is going on.

Comment: @ZuzuJH I ended up downgrading to 3.1.4 and removing the groovy dependencies from the project gradle file. Bit of a pain, but it the best I could do for lack of time.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and still facing this issue, does anyone know the fix yet?

Comment: Im facing this error in android studio (react-native) /Users/sullah/Downloads/Projects/FrontEnd/team-lms-field-app-old/node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android/gradle.properties (Operation not permitted)

previously app was working fine but since yesterday Im seeing this error and when I try to run the app it crashes on launch showing no errors while metro bundler also doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing allocated memory on this property **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3000m** in gradle.properties fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Build -> Clean Project
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once I upgraded to the new IDE (based on Intellij 2019.3); but once i upgraded my OpenJDK from 8 to 11, it worked. Also make sure you have enough heap RAM gradle.propertise like 3GB > `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3000m`

Answer (score 0):

We had this Issue as well.
We have a quite big build.gradle on app level the critical part looked like this:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

  ext.fancyAppNameVersionDate = fancyAppNameVersionDate

  buildTypes {
    debug {
       //[...]
    }
    release {
        //[...]
    }
  }

  defaultConfig {
      //[...]
  }
}
```

The broken part is the

```
ext.fancyAppNameVersionDate = fancyAppNameVersionDate
```

I do not know why it was written there, because it has no use and I do not know why it is a problem now and not before. But I deleted that line and it fixed the problem.

This is a specific case but I just tried a build.gradle of a new project in our old one and it worked. After that I deleted every part that was not part of a default generated build.gradle until it worked. That way I found the smelly line.

Edit: The problem is the reassignment of the extra property

```
ext.fancyAppNameVersionDate
```

with itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation "build.gradle" imported another gradle file via

```
apply from: "cordova.gradle"
```

The Groovy parser therefore exceeded the stack limit.

What I did is just copy the contents of the imported gradle configuration in the initial one instead of the import with `apply.from`, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changed both the AGP version and Gradle Version to another. maybe to a higher version, maybe a lower version, it depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the application was built with the Jvm default configuration.
Changed in `build.gradle` solve my problem.

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m', '-Xss1024m']
    }
}
```